# Privacy: what personal data does Apple share with an app developer, when I buy an app?

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id, mac-appstore, privacy

What personal data is shared with an app developer when I buy an app? I am interested in Mac App Store and also iOS App Store.

Do they see my real name, or location, or something different? I found, with a search engine, only what data an app developer can collect when running the app.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No personal data is shared with an app developer on app purchase.

The aggregate information available for app units in iTunes Connect App Analytics is:

- Purchase date (no more granularity available than cumulative over 24h period)
- Device type (e.g. "iPhone" or "iPad")
- Platform version (e.g. "iOS 10.3", x.x is the most detail available)
- Region (e.g. "Europe" or "Asia Pacific")
- Territory (e.g. "United Kingdom")
- Source type (e.g. "App Store Search", "App Store Browse")
- App referrer (e.g. "Google Chrome", given where a *third-party* app linked to product page)
- Web referrer (e.g. "georgegarside.com")
- Campaign (custom string linked to by iTunes product link URL parameter)

---

When you run the app:

- the app can ask you to agree to share your Contacts, which would allow the app to access your ‘me card’ for your name.
- the app can ask you to enable Location Services for the app, so the app can obtain your location.

In both of these cases, the app will ask for permission at OS level and you can accept or reject the permission. These permissions are only asked for if the app requests it — it's uncommon to request such information unless the app needs it for your benefit.

Comment: I think the main part of this answer could be improved by being more explicit: Does Apple really not share any information at all with the developers? Do they maybe provided data like the time and country of the download? It might be arguable whether these should be considered 'private data', but I think it's still interesting in the context of this question.

Comment: @Emil Sure, I've added all the data available for my apps in App Analytics to my answer.

Comment: @Emil I just wanted to add that data from App Analytics is only from users who have opted in to sharing app analytics. Here is a quote from the iTunes Connect App Analytics page: *We only show data from users who have agreed to share their diagnostics and usage information with app developers. In the last 30 days, 22% of all users that installed apps agreed to share their data.* To clarify what this means, at the OS level (both within iOS and macOS) users have to opt-in to sharing their app analytics data, otherwise this data is **not** available to developers.

Comment: @Monomeeth That’s true, but for the Installations metric, which is opt-in. The App Units metric is collected separately to the opt-in analytics.